# Ambiguous Quantifiers

Tags: predicate-logic

i wondered what kind of quantifiers do not involves ambiguous reading ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. is True: pick $x = Andy$ and $y = Ben$:

Andy likes Ben, so

$$like(a,b) = True$$

, and so

$$like(a, b) \lor \neg linguist(a) = True$$

as well.

Also: Ben is taller than Andy, so

$$taller(b,a) = True$$

, and so

$$(like(a, b)\lor \neg linguist(a))\land taller(b,a) = True$$

, and so

$$∃x∃y((like(x, y)\lor \neg linguist(x)) \land taller(y,x)) = True$$

For 2 you got the right answer

3. is True:

Consider Chris: everyone likes Chris, and so

for any $z$, $like(z,c) = True$

Therefore, for any $z$, $Tall(c) \rightarrow like(z,c) = True$

and so

$$\forall z (Tall(c) \rightarrow like(z,c)) = True$$

and thus

$$\neg \forall z (Tall(c) \rightarrow like(z,c)) = False$$

and therefore

$$\exists y (taller(y,x) \lor like(c,y)) \land \neg \forall z (Tall(c) \rightarrow like(z,c)) = False$$

and therefore

$$\forall x (\exists y (taller(y,x) \lor like(c,y)) \land \neg \forall z (Tall(c) \rightarrow like(z,c))) = False$$

and therefore

$$\neg \forall x (\exists y (taller(y,x) \lor like(c,y)) \land \neg \forall z (Tall(c) \rightarrow like(z,c))) = True$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! :)

Comment: @Lisa You're welcome!

Comment: @Lisa Wait!  I believe 3 is true ... let me revisit ...

Comment: @Lisa  Yeah 3 is True, not False. I updated my Answer. 2 is definitely True though ... can you explain that in the way I did 1 and 3?

Comment: Hello! After reading your explanation i think i just miss out one step throughout the computation thats why i got the wrong answer. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @Lisa  It's good you were able to find your mistake! :)

Comment: thank you! :) its very helpful!!!